# File upload going into POST instead of FILE

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file onto a server. Whenever I submit, the php global array $_FILES is empty. My file keeps going into $_POST.

```
        <form action="process.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES['uploaded_file']);
var_dump($_POST['uploaded_file']);
```

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File not uploading PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807280/file-not-uploading-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` like this

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` into html
like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How is this different from the first answer?