# move_uploaded_file() does not work except if destination is the main directory (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, ubuntu

I want to save an uploaded image to a folder up in the directory. I have tested these destinations:
`$destination_path = __DIR__."/../img/";` and `$destination_path = "../img/";` and `$destination_path = "/../img/";`

I also tried the following and it does not work

```
chdir('../img/');
$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Only this worked for me only if the file is placed in the website main directory!!:

```
 $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

My code:-

```
$destination_path = "/../img/";
$name = rand (100,1000);
$result = 0;
$filename=$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) ;

   // setting up the directory of the file uploaded
$target_path = $destination_path . $name .".". $ext;

   //making sure the file has been uploaded in the specified directory
if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
 {
 $result = 1;
 }
```

Comment: @Kaddath I updated the question.

Comment: Do you have an error or warning if you remove the error suppression `@` from `move_uploaded_file`? (why is it here in the first place? this is the kind of function you'd want to know if something goes wrong)

Comment: There is no error when I use your suggestion and remove `@`. I use it because the file return a json with some data including `$result` that would indicate if `move_uploaded_file` worked or not without the actual error reporting.

Comment: As read through the net, it seems easy and straight forward function to use but here it does not work. Only `$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;` works if php file is placed in main directory so that the images are all uploaded to the main directory. I tried to place it in the `/img` folder and it does not work.

Comment: so, when you use `$destination_path = "/../img/";` without error suppression, it doesn't work but you have not error at all? Following the Docs, the only case i see it could happen is if `filename` is invalid, other cases throw errors. Side note: `$name = rand (100,1000);` is not guaranteed to produce a name that doesn't exist already, you should add a check here.

Comment: What kind of OS are you using on your server machine?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and PHP 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload any type of file to the server using PHP 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326754/how-to-upload-any-type-of-file-to-the-server-using-php-5)

Comment: @NimeShPatel It is not. See my answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running Ubuntu. The issue was a permission problem. I ran this to fix it:

```
 sudo chmod 777 /var/www/work_pathname/the_upload_pathname
```