# How to block uploaded files?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Based on this two questions:

- [simple file upload script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207379/simple-file-upload-script)
- [Easy way to password-protect php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115719/easy-way-to-password-protect-php-page)

I wrote an easy password protected file uploader.

So I have password verifier named **password.php**

```
    <body>
        <?php
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            {?>
                <form method="POST" action="password.php">
                    Password <input type="password" name="pass"></input>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok"></input>
                </form>
            <?}
                if($pass == "admin")
                    {
                    include("../uploader.html");
                    }
        ?>
    </body>
```

As you can tell from the code. If pass is ok it includes **uploader.html** from out of **public_html** folder.

```
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
            <input name="thefile" type="file" /><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </body>
```

In the end we use upload.php to send "thefile" to folder named **files**.

```
    <body>
        <?php
            $thefile_tmp = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];
            $thefile_name = $_FILES['thefile']['name'];
            if(is_uploaded_file($thefile_tmp)) 
                {
                move_uploaded_file($thefile_tmp, "files/$thefile_name");
                }
        ?>
    </body>
```

I changed **files** folder's chmod to 777 and everything works fine.

I gave the password to bunch of students and I asked them to send me reports. A student now can anonymously upload a malicious file (lets say **loop.php**) and open it in a browser **.../files/loop.php**.

So I want to protect my site from such stories. I tried to set **files** folder's chmod to 773 or 776. On 776 my code lost ability to send files. On 773 you can still open things in **files** folder.

> **Question/Request** Is there an easy way to block uploaded files from opening?

---

**Good easy solution which I used**

Based on @Fred -ii- suggestion I added to **upload.php** an extension verifier. Now it look like this

```
<body>
    <?php
        $thefile_tmp = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];
        $thefile_name = $_FILES['thefile']['name'];
        $thefile_ext = pathinfo($thefile_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(is_uploaded_file($thefile_tmp))
            {
            if( $thefile_ext == 'zip')
                {
                move_uploaded_file($thefile_tmp, "files/$thefile_name");
                }
            }
    ?>
</body>
```

---

**Alternative solution**

As @alexander.polomodov answeres. I just put .htaccess file in **files** folder and still files can be send, but no one can access it. This method does not fit me, cause I wanted students to be able to peep at each others reports.

Comment: You could remove the .php extension from the file when uploaded. so when the server gets an request on the recent uploaded file it does not execute the file.

Comment: *"I asked for .zip files"* - Yeah, here in comments. Not in your question. What stops you from adding to the array from the possible dupe? Did you not go through all of the answers in there?

Comment: you deleted your comment about *"I asked for .zip files"* and now you're no longer responding. see the guy's answer below then and one of those links could be one of the dupes then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry. i do not catch up. Now I am trying to check whether I have Apache or Nginx on my server.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I used solution you put in the link and it works fine. 

PS. Sorry for deleting previous comment.

Comment: great glad to hear it. Since you used it, it should be closed as a duplicate. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1):

What webserver do you use?

1) If you use Apache follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess)

Add file files/.htaccess with string:

```
Deny from all
```

2) If you use Nginx follow this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/137907/how-to-restrict-access-to-directory-and-subdirs)

Add to your nginx config:

```
location /files {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: You can try first variant, it's probably your solution, because apache is common webserver for hostings.

Comment: I tried to add .htaccess, but file did not appear on server

Comment: How you usually upload file on your webser?

Comment: By WinSCP, but to terminal I log by mRemoteNG.

Comment: you add your .htacces file into files directory and can't see it in WinSCP or on websers? I question you because it's normal that you can't see .htaccess files on websers (these files for servers not for people:) )

Comment: I do not see in in WinSCP.
EDIT. I see. Now I cant acess it by browser. So it works. But how to change it back?

Comment: just remove `.htaccess` file or remove string `Deny from all` from it

Comment: But .htaccess is invisible in WinSCP. I deleted folder and created new one.

Comment: I can't help with WinSCP because I prefer to use linux (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu, Centos) or FreeBSD fork with name MacOs:)

Comment: Ok. I checked and your method works just fine. .htaccess file do the job.