# PHP upload file web form

Tags: php, forms

i'm trying to create a form that lets the visitor upload image files. I have been using the code below but keep receiving the "`not set`" error as if `$_FILES['image']` isn't picking up the image file.

Can anyone see any errors here?

Form code:

```
<h1>Contact form test</h1>
<form action="php/form.php" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" required><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" required><br>
  <p>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

php code:

```
// Set variables
$firstname = secure($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = secure($_POST['lastname']);

// Form Security
function secure($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
// File upload
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));       
    $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");          
    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }          
      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be exactly 2 MB';
      }          
      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
}else{
    echo "not set";
}
```

Comment: use enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207379/simple-file-upload-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag

```
<form action="php/form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" required><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" required><br>

    <p>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 3):

put `enctype="multipart/form-data`" in form tag

Answer (score 1):

Just `adds a multipart attribute for form tag`, which is necessary if you would like to use the form to upload files with. The `enctype attribute` specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

```
<form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
//you code here
</form>
```

Also ,the `enctype attribute` can be used only if `method="post"`.